# the `<active>1</active>` filed meaning in libvirt snapshot xml

Tags: kvm, qemu, libvirt

I just found out the xml file in `/var/lib/libvirt/qemu/snapshot/<domain>/*.xml` contains `<active>1</active>` field. But the dumped xml does not have this. What does this field mean? Why some of them are `<active>0</active>` others are `<active>1</active>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The active indicate current snapshot. There seems no way to add it via XML. But virsh can remark the snapshot to current one.